# Refresing expired certificates on k8s

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate

I ran into issue with expired certificates on k8s cluster. I am running version 1.6.1 for over a year now, meaning that my certificates expired and I have to renew them.
In newer versions this is already done automatically, but I currently can not upgrade my cluster to higher version, so I have to create certificates manually.

I came across following [link](https://medium.com/@AnushkaSandaru1/how-to-change-expired-certificates-in-kubernetes-cluster-5d3feb9d9838), where it is described step-by-step, but I am actually already stuck on creating openssl.cnf file, as I am missing parameters. At the same time, this option is using .pem key, while on cluster currently .crt and .key pairs are used.

Any suggestion how to move forward with this? I have also tried running `kubeadm alpha phase certs selfsign` command, which created new certificates, yet I am still running into issue that api-server is refusing TSL handshake.

```
http: TLS handshake error from IP:port: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Thank you and best regards,

Bostjan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a detailed [guide on how to generate certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/).**

While you are following that guide look out for a few gotchas:

- Make sure your CA certificate is valid for the period you are trying to extend the other certificates to. The validity of any certificates signed by the CA certificate are *also* limited by the expiration date of the CA certificate.
- If the validity period of the CA certificate itself is too short you are in a pickle. Replacing that certificate will require modifying all kubeconfigs (operators, cluster components).
- For the same reason as above, make very sure you don't overwrite the CA key/certificate accidentaly.
- When replacing the certificate for the apiserver you will need to restart the apiserver. The apiserver does not reread the certificate automatically.

Comment: Hello Janos, thank you very much for information. I am using v1.6.1 for which this documentation does not exist, I will try it anyway. Thing is I don't have server.crt, but I am using some others (e.g. apiserver, apiserver-kubelet-client), I presume I create them same way as they did with server.crt? Also it seems I already have ca.crt, which has CA:TRUE (presume this means it is certificate authority?)

Comment: Yes, `ca.crt` is the CA. `server.crt/.key` is used an example in the guide. Use `apiserver.crt/.key`, etc.

Comment: Hello Janos. Thanks again for your help. I have created those certificates anew, put them in same path (used by apiserver and control-manager) and did systemctl restart kubelet. Still issue persists though, is there anywhere else where I have to set up those new certificates?

Comment: Well done :-) Restarting the kubelet **does not** restart the apiserver, which of course can be unexpected. You can try `docker ps | grep apiserver` and use `docker rm -f` on the apiserver containers. Alternatively, reboot the machine.